# Spark: create DataFrame with specified schema fields

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, create case class to specify schema, then create RDD from a file and convert it to DF. e.g.

```
case class Example(name: String, age: Long)
val exampleDF = spark.sparkContext
    .textFile("example.txt")
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(attributes => Example(attributes(0), attributes(1).toInt))
    .toDF()
```

The question is, if the content in the txt file is like "ABCDE12345FGHIGK67890", without any symbols or spaces. How to extract specified length of string for the schema field. e.g. extract 'BCD' for name and '23' for age. Is this possible to use map and split?
Thanks !!!

Comment: Is this fixed for the name it is only the 2nd to 4th field and 7th and 8th for age ?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subString` to pull the data from specific index as below

```
case class Example (name : String, age: Int)

val example = spark.sparkContext
    .textFile("test.txt")
    .map(line => Example(line.substring(1, 4),  line.substring(6,8).toInt)).toDF()

example.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| BCD| 23|
| BCD| 23|
| BCD| 23|
+----+---+
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the map function where you are splitting by commas, just put a function that converts the input string to a list of values in the required order.